# Realm crash when trying to access the configuration

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I added the Object class to the Aps and Alert class and now the application crashes when trying to access the Realm configuration with an error:

> Thread 1: Exception: "Invalid class subset list:\n- 'PushNotification.aps' links to class 'Aps', which is missing from the list of classes managed by the Realm"

I tried to raise the schema version, delete completely Derived Data, delete the app - nothing helped.

**Realm configuration file**

```
struct RealmGatewayImp: RealmGateway {
  let configuration: Realm.Configuration

  private init(config: Realm.Configuration) {
    configuration = config
  }

  var realm: Realm {
    try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
  }

  // MARK: - Push notification
  // The app crashes here 
  private static let pushConfig = Realm.Configuration(
    fileURL: try! Path.inSharedContainer("pushNotifications.realm"),
    schemaVersion: 1,
    deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true,
    objectTypes: [PushNotification.self])

  public static var push: RealmGatewayImp = {
    RealmGatewayImp(config: pushConfig)
  }()
}
```

**Parent class**

```
@objcMembers
final class PushNotification: Object, Codable {
  dynamic var accCodeIso: String?
  dynamic var account: String?
  dynamic var accType: String?
  dynamic var amount: String?
  dynamic var aps: Aps?
  dynamic var commentary: String?
  dynamic var corrAccCodeIso: String?
  dynamic var corrAccount: String?
  dynamic var corrAccType: String?
  dynamic var date: Date?
  dynamic var docType: String?
  dynamic var id: String?
  dynamic var payAmount: String?

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    "id"
  }
}
```

**Class of the parameter**

```
@objcMembers
final class Aps: Object, Codable {
  dynamic var alert: Alert?
}

@objcMembers
final class Alert: Object, Codable {
  dynamic var body: String?
  dynamic var title: String?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to specify which objects Realm is managing, it needs to be a complete list. Instead of

```
objectTypes: [PushNotification.self])
```

try

```
objectTypes: [PushNotification.self, Aps.self, Alert.self])
```